# How do i change the values on the axes in the plot using tkinter and matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using tkinter to create a plot containing two curves. I managed to plot them but it displays only positive values on the x axis.

```
    graph = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    A0=1
    b=.1

    y = [-((A0/pi)*(1-b*x))**0.5 for x in range(-101, (int(1/b)+1))]
    z = [((A0 / pi) * (1 - b * x)) ** 0.5 for x in range(-101, (int(1/b)+1))]

    plot1 = graph.add_subplot(111)
    plot2 = graph.add_subplot(111)

    plot1.plot(y)
    plot2.plot(z)

    canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(graph, master=self)
    canvas1.draw()
    canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5 )
```

How do i make the values to be the values of x used during the creation of the curves?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could transform your code into a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that is a piece of code we can run without having to edit it and guess what the import statement are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass *both* x and y to `plot()`. You can also simplify and speed up your code using `numpy`. Also, you don't need to create two subplots.

```py
x = np.arange(-101, (int(1/b)+1))
y = -((A0/np.pi)*(1-b*x))**0.5
z = ((A0 /np.pi) * (1 - b * x)) ** 0.5

plot1 = graph.add_subplot(111)

plot1.plot(x,y)
plot1.plot(x,z)
```